# Unable to install bind-utils in RHEL 7.3, dependency error on bind-license

Tags: rhel, bind, amazon-ec2, aws, dig

I'm trying to install `dig` through `bind-utils` on an AWS EC2 RHEL 7.3 instance, but I get a dependency error.

`Requires: bind-license = 32:9.9.4-37.el7`

but

`Installed: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.noarch`

I tried installing the required version like so since is is available, but without success:

```
[root@ip-171-32-49-95 tmp]# yum install bind-license-9.9.4-37.el7.noarch
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Package matching 32:bind-license-9.9.4-37.el7.noarch already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

What gives? How can I get `bind-utils` to install here?

Here is the full transaction log:

```
[root@ip-171-32-49-95 tmp]# yum install bind-utils
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.9.4-37.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 32:9.9.4-37.el7 for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libbind9.so.90()(64bit) for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdns.so.100()(64bit) for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libisc.so.95()(64bit) for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libisccc.so.90()(64bit) for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libisccfg.so.90()(64bit) for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblwres.so.90()(64bit) for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.9.4-37.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: bind-license = 32:9.9.4-37.el7 for package: 32:bind-libs-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 32:bind-libs-9.9.4-37.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
           Requires: bind-license = 32:9.9.4-37.el7
           Installed: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.noarch (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-38.el7_3
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-14.el7
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-14.el7_0.1
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-18.el7.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-18.el7
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-18.el7_1.1.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-18.el7_1.1
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-18.el7_1.2.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-18.el7_1.2
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-18.el7_1.3.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-18.el7_1.3
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-18.el7_1.4.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-18.el7_1.4
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-18.el7_1.5.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-18.el7_1.5
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.1.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.1
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.2.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.2
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.3
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.4.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.4
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-37.el7.noarch (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-37.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install that specific version? Why not just `yum install bind-utils`? Have you added any 3rd party libraries to the system?

Comment: I am just trying to `yum install bind-utils`.

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -e --nodeps bind-libs-lite bind-license
yum install bind-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and found it was a specific package version. In file **/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo** under `[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional]` I added the line: `exclude=32:bind-devel-9.9.4-50.el7_3.1.x86_64`

Block your version and section accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed same problem via `yum downgrade`, Thanks for @john-king and @jeff-schaller .

```
$ sudo yum downgrade -y bind-license bind-libs-lite
```

The dependency error in my case.

```
$ sudo yum install -y bind-utils
...
Error: Package: 32:bind-libs-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2.x86_64 (ltzwk-upadte)
           Requires: bind-license = 32:9.9.4-38.el7_3.2
           Installed: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-50.el7_3.1.noarch (@updates)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-50.el7_3.1
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7.noarch (ltzwk-base)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.1.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.1
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.2.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.2
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.3
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-29.el7_2.4.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-29.el7_2.4
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-37.el7.noarch (ltzwk-base)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-37.el7
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-38.el7_3
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.1.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-38.el7_3.1
           Available: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2.noarch (ltzwk-upadte)
               bind-license = 32:9.9.4-38.el7_3.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```